# Why does it use "anything"?

Tags: difference

I have run across some sentence like this "people typically fear anything which is small probability".
Here, I can't quite get a catch of the meaning of "anything". Why does it use *anything*? Is it possible that "something or everything" don't work?

And I want to know the exact meaning of *anything* at this sentence. What is the different Nuance?

Comment: *something* takes some parts; *everything* takes all the parts; *anything* takes random parts inside of the *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* is a word that means one of a group, but it doesn't matter which one.

*Any* can modify a noun (*any X*) to mean one of a group of X - but we don't care which X in the group.

It functions as the determiner for a noun so it takes the spot that an article or word like "this", "these" would occupy.

> Give me any folder from your stack and I'll help you work on it.

The person here doesn't care which folder he/she gets.

If we don't know what X is, or X could be multiple possible things and we don't care which one, then the pronoun *anything* can be used.

*Thing* is a very generic word that means (from Google) "an object that one need not, cannot, or does not wish to give a specific name to", so *any thing* -> *anything* makes logical sense.

> A: I have chocolate candies and apples.  Which do you want?
>
> B: I don't care.  Give me anything that you want.

or

> A: What's in the cave?
>
> B: I don't know.  It could be anything.

---

*Some* is a word that can mean, among other things, one of a group which is known to someone else but not necessarily the person speaking/writing.

When used with plural nouns, it can still mean this, but can also mean "more than one but not a great amount."

> She had some folder in her hand.  I didn't know which one.  (The speaker/writer is saying that the folder seemed familiar, known, or important to whoever "she" is.)
>
> In this box I think I have some folder I'm supposed to be working on.  (When you use *some* with an item you have, you are saying you don't know about it but should know about.)
>
> She had some folders in her hand = She had a few folders in her hand + that they are familiar, known, or important to her.

*Some* + *thing* = *something* in the similar fashion as *anything* above.

So there is often a subtle difference between *anything* and *something* and it usually has to do with how familiar or known the "thing" or possible "thing" is to a third party.

---

*Every* is a word that means ALL of a group.  Works like *any* and *some* above grammatically.

It's also used colloquially to mean "anything that could be in a group", though there still is the faint implication that there could be "more than one."

So it's possible that a speaker may say this:

> people typically fear everything which is small probability

and mean the same as this

> people typically fear anything which is small probability

But since there is a possibility for confusion here, you should avoid mixing the two in writing.